# Angular 2 mapping JSON array to Model class

Tags: angular

I get the below response from server when checked in Postman

```
[
    {
        "name": "1001"
    }
]
```

I am trying to map it to the model in Angular

Component:

```
models: Model[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.client_service.getValues()
          .then((valueFromService) => {
            this.models = valueFromService; //valueFromService is undefined
          } )
          .catch((err) => {
            this.load_error = true;
            const BODY = JSON.parse(err._body);
            this.error_text = BODY.message;
          });
      }
```

Model:

```
export class Model {
  public name: string;

  constructor (nm: string) {
    this.name = nm;
  }
```

Service:

```
    getValues(): Promise<Model[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(URL)
      .toPromise()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.json());
        response.json() as Model [];})
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I tried to map response to Model [], response.json() to Model [], etc but I always get undefined.

Is the model wrong or the code in the http service?

Comment: Can you please add the code that is showing the response as undefined?

Comment: In the `then` line of your service, I believe you will need to `return` that value. At the moment, that does nothing. Alternately, if you're using the newer `HttpClient` instead of `Http`, you can probably do `this.http.get<Model[]>(url)`

Comment: Well, you're not returning anything from your code so it should be `undefined`. This might be a typo mistake where a simple removal of `{ .. }` should do the trick. Also, there is no need for [manual constructor assignments.](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters/), just use the constructor.